# How to get size in bytes of bson documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, bson

Is the int value returned by size() function of bson document the number of bytes ? (not able to find the details of this API).
 How can I get the size of a bson document in bytes? Here is my code.

```
import org.bson.Document;

MongoDatabase db...;
MongoCollection<Document> mongoCollection = db.getCollection(...);
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = mongoCollection.find().iterator();
Document doc = cursor.next();
int size = doc.size(); // does this return number of bytes 
// how to get size of doc in bytes?
```

Comment: @Magnus looking for size of org.bson.Document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the document as a `RawBsonDocument` then use the `getByteBuffer().remaining()` method.

```java
MongoCollection<RawBsonDocument> mongoCollection = db.getCollection(collectionName, RawBsonDocument.class);
MongoCursor<RawBsonDocument> cursor = mongoCollection.find().iterator();
RawBsonDocument doc = cursor.next();
int size = doc.getByteBuffer().remaining()
```

Comment: Using ByteBuf.capacity() is incorrect.  Use ByteBuf.remaining() instead.  The capacity is the size of the wrapped byte array, which may be larger than the actual document.  Using ByteBuf.remaining() will tell you how many of those bytes are actually taken up by the document.

Comment: @jyemin is right, I compared the result of remaining to capacity, and for me capacity was larger and remaining matched the output of bsonsize function from Mongo shell.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to know the size the object will take before it is in the Collection, I used this code where **o** is the Object to test:

```
    BsonDocument bsonDocument = BsonDocumentWrapper.asBsonDocument(o, getMongoCollection().getCodecRegistry());
    RawBsonDocument rawBsonDocument = RawBsonDocument.parse(bsonDocument.toJson() );

    int bsonSize = rawBsonDocument.getByteBuffer().remaining();
```

This is particularly useful if you want to prevent objects that might be exceeding the maximum size of 16Mb: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: What if the document would be >2GB? `remaining` returns an int.