# MongoDB Java driver when storing data greater than 16MB usually gives BSONMaximumSizeExceededException but sometimes give MongoWriteException

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

My code works in the following manner.

1. I have a document saved in MongoDB collection, I fetch that document.
   2 Update this document on Java layer, add values in a key of array type.
2. Then using the replaceOne() function (with upsert as true) of MongoCollection.java class, I pass on _id as filter and the complete object as the object to be replaced.
3. If this document Bson size is greater than 16 MB, it gives BSONMaximumSizeExceededException, I catch it and in the catch block I save this document in the GridFS.
4. If this document's size is less than 16MB, it gets replaced.

So in step 4 I expect and 99% times get BSONMaximumSizeExceededException, but this one to two time I got MongoWriteException.

The description of MongoWriteException is also similar to BSONMaximumSizeExceededException
The exception goes like this

Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoWriteException: Write results unavailable from  :: caused by :: BSONObj size: 16793731 (0x1004083) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB).

Can anyone explain why I did not get BSONMaximumSizeExceededException and instead got MongoWriteException?

Or is there any other way I can know at Java Layer that my document has grown greater than 16MB?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34545555/how-to-get-size-in-bytes-of-bson-documents, second answer. It explains how to get the size of a BSON object before it is written.

Comment: I have a java object, to get the size, according to the comment I have to first convert into BsonDocument, then to Json document. I thinks it is a lot of conversion for such a simple task. Is there any other wat available?

Answer (score 0):

Kishore Babu Diyyana
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes.

The maximum document size helps ensure that a single document cannot use excessive amount of RAM or, during transmission, excessive amount of bandwidth. To store documents larger than the maximum size, MongoDB provides the GridFS API. See mongofiles and the documentation for your driver for more information about GridFS.